# How to change format of DatePicker in Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I currently have the DatePicker in my project but there are problems due to the need that I need a specific format to be returned, not the regional format.

Anyway in VS I could manipulate the format to how I wanted but in Blend there is no option, can anyone help me out here?

btw this isn't any custom style.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? By "manipulating the format", do you mean setting `SelectedDateFormat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477908/how-to-change-date-format-in-silverlight-datepicker-control/675464#675464), the DatePicker cannot do this on its own. You need to do this manually in the code.