# Silverlight DatePicker custom date format

Tags: c#, date, silverlight, datepicker, silverlight-5.0

I want to set silverlight DatePicker date format into "MM/dd/yyyy" format. I tried **convertors**, and setting **StringFormat** in **DisplayDate** and **SelectedDate** properties. No luck so far.
I **can not** change application wide culture short date format string to achieve this, need this format only in specific DatePicker.

```
<controls:DatePicker x:Name="GotoDatePicker2" 
                  SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                     DisplayDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                </controls:DatePicker>
```

Any workaround regarding this matter ?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on your problem. It is _really_ hard to tell what is going on without see your work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no easy answer here if you can't change the whole culture as explain here: [How to change date format in Silverlight DatePicker control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477908/how-to-change-date-format-in-silverlight-datepicker-control)

For me the best option is to define a custom control template, so you have a full control on the textbox of the datepicker to create the required format.

Hope it helps.